# Feedback Comments Email Notification To Student

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to send the email notification to students, whenever the tutor gives feedback on the students assignment. But the email is not triggering correctly. The email notification code which i had written is placed in right function, that is  **set_editor_text**. Any help will be appreciable. I have highlighted the code of the email triggering.

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * This file contains the definition for the library class for comment feedback plugin
 *
 * @package   assignfeedback_comments
 * @copyright 2012 NetSpot {@link http://www.netspot.com.au}
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

// File component for feedback comments.
define('ASSIGNFEEDBACK_COMMENTS_COMPONENT', 'assignfeedback_comments');

// File area for feedback comments.
define('ASSIGNFEEDBACK_COMMENTS_FILEAREA', 'feedback');

/**
 * Library class for comment feedback plugin extending feedback plugin base class.
 *
 * @package   assignfeedback_comments
 * @copyright 2012 NetSpot {@link http://www.netspot.com.au}
 * @license   http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */
class assign_feedback_comments extends assign_feedback_plugin {

    /**
     * Get the name of the online comment feedback plugin.
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_name() {
        return get_string('pluginname', 'assignfeedback_comments');
    }

    /**
     * Get the feedback comment from the database.
     *
     * @param int $gradeid
     * @return stdClass|false The feedback comments for the given grade if it exists.
     *                        False if it doesn't.
     */
    public function get_feedback_comments($gradeid) {
        global $DB;
        return $DB->get_record('assignfeedback_comments', array('grade'=>$gradeid));
    }

    /**
     * Get quickgrading form elements as html.
     *
     * @param int $userid The user id in the table this quickgrading element relates to
     * @param mixed $grade - The grade data - may be null if there are no grades for this user (yet)
     * @return mixed - A html string containing the html form elements required for quickgrading
     */
    public function get_quickgrading_html($userid, $grade) {
        $commenttext = '';
        if ($grade) {
            $feedbackcomments = $this->get_feedback_comments($grade->id);
            if ($feedbackcomments) {
                $commenttext = $feedbackcomments->commenttext;
            }
        }

        $pluginname = get_string('pluginname', 'assignfeedback_comments');
        $labeloptions = array('for'=>'quickgrade_comments_' . $userid,
                              'class'=>'accesshide');
        $textareaoptions = array('name'=>'quickgrade_comments_' . $userid,
                                 'id'=>'quickgrade_comments_' . $userid,
                                 'class'=>'quickgrade');
        return html_writer::tag('label', $pluginname, $labeloptions) .
               html_writer::tag('textarea', $commenttext, $textareaoptions);
    }

    /**
     * Has the plugin quickgrading form element been modified in the current form submission?
     *
     * @param int $userid The user id in the table this quickgrading element relates to
     * @param stdClass $grade The grade
     * @return boolean - true if the quickgrading form element has been modified
     */
    public function is_quickgrading_modified($userid, $grade) {
        $commenttext = '';
        if ($grade) {
            $feedbackcomments = $this->get_feedback_comments($grade->id);
            if ($feedbackcomments) {
                $commenttext = $feedbackcomments->commenttext;
            }
        }
        // Note that this handles the difference between empty and not in the quickgrading
        // form at all (hidden column).
        $newvalue = optional_param('quickgrade_comments_' . $userid, false, PARAM_RAW);
        return ($newvalue !== false) && ($newvalue != $commenttext);
    }

    /**
     * Has the comment feedback been modified?
     *
     * @param stdClass $grade The grade object.
     * @param stdClass $data Data from the form submission.
     * @return boolean True if the comment feedback has been modified, else false.
     */
    public function is_feedback_modified(stdClass $grade, stdClass $data) {
        $commenttext = '';
        if ($grade) {
            $feedbackcomments = $this->get_feedback_comments($grade->id);
            if ($feedbackcomments) {
                $commenttext = $feedbackcomments->commenttext;
            }
        }

        $formtext = $data->assignfeedbackcomments_editor['text'];

        // Need to convert the form text to use @@PLUGINFILE@@ and format it so we can compare it with what is stored in the DB.
        if (isset($data->assignfeedbackcomments_editor['itemid'])) {
            $formtext = file_rewrite_urls_to_pluginfile($formtext, $data->assignfeedbackcomments_editor['itemid']);
            $formtext = format_text($formtext, FORMAT_HTML);
        }

        if ($commenttext == $formtext) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Override to indicate a plugin supports quickgrading.
     *
     * @return boolean - True if the plugin supports quickgrading
     */
    public function supports_quickgrading() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Return a list of the text fields that can be imported/exported by this plugin.
     *
     * @return array An array of field names and descriptions. (name=>description, ...)
     */
    public function get_editor_fields() {
        return array('comments' => get_string('pluginname', 'assignfeedback_comments'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the saved text content from the editor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param int $gradeid
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_editor_text($name, $gradeid) {
        if ($name == 'comments') {
            $feedbackcomments = $this->get_feedback_comments($gradeid);
            if ($feedbackcomments) {
                return $feedbackcomments->commenttext;
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Get the saved text content from the editor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $gradeid
     * @return string
     */
    public function set_editor_text($name, $value, $gradeid) {
        global $DB;

        if ($name == 'comments') {
            $feedbackcomment = $this->get_feedback_comments($gradeid);
            if ($feedbackcomment) {
                $feedbackcomment->commenttext = $value;
                return $DB->update_record('assignfeedback_comments', $feedbackcomment);


            } else {
                $feedbackcomment = new stdClass();
                $feedbackcomment->commenttext = $value;
                $feedbackcomment->commentformat = FORMAT_HTML;
                $feedbackcomment->grade = $gradeid;
                $feedbackcomment->assignment = $this->assignment->get_instance()->id;

                return $DB->insert_record('assignfeedback_comments', $feedbackcomment) > 0;
                                **$tooo = $DB->get_record('role', array('shortname' => 'student'));

                    }
                }



         }
                         $tooo = $DB->get_record('role', array('shortname' => 'student'));
                $too =  $DB->get_records('role_assignments', array('roleid' => $tooo->id));
                $pageNos = array();
                foreach ($too as $new) {
                    if(!in_array($new->userid,$pageNos))
                    {
                        $t = $DB->get_record('assign_submission', array('roleid'=>$new->roleid));
                        $tt = $DB->get_record('assign', array('id'=>$t->assignment));
                        $tttt=$DB->get_record('groups_members', array('groupid' => $t->groupid, 'userid' => $new->userid));
                        $pageNos[] = $new->userid;
                        $name = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $tttt->userid));
                        $body = "Hi";
                        email_to_user($name,$USER,'hi','The text of the message',$body);**
                    }
                }


            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is a wall of code to figure out - perhaps you can reduce this to the minimum required to reproduce the problem rather than all your code? Also - explain what does happen

Comment: Hi, i have reduced the code.  Actually the red color highlighted ones are the sql tables. I am doing inner joins and getting the data. Whatever is in the array is the column names.

Comment: IN set_editor_text function if you go to the end means you can see the email notification code. PLease check once and let me know if you did'nt understood the code. The problem is, if the tutor comments on the students assignment means, the student should receive the email notification. The place where i kept the code is correct, but the email is not going to student. i dont know why?

Comment: Have you added roleid field in 'assign_submission' table ?  $t = $DB->get_record('assign_submission', array('roleid'=>$new->roleid));